# File Empty and returns a null value all the time

Tags: java, android, file, file-io

I have a few areas that could be the possible source to my issue, and I'm hoping the I am just being stupid and forgetting a small detail. But basically I'm making an app that reads from a data(txt) file and puts that into a hashmap, then it uses that hashmap to get a corresponding integer that goes along with a string. If you're confused it makes more sense in the code.

So first when the app loads it calls as one of its first method in the MainActivity class the method firstTime() that returns a true or false:

```
    private boolean firstTime() {
    //checks if the needed folders are in place
    File storelist = new File(this.getFilesDir()  + File.separator +"Stores");
    File listnames = new File(this.getFilesDir()  + File.separator +"Lists");
    System.out.println("Store File: "+new File(storelist+File.separator + "Sample Fresh.txt").getAbsolutePath());
    if(storelist.isDirectory() && listnames.isDirectory() && new File(storelist+File.separator + "Sample Fresh.txt").exists()){
        return false;
    }
    else{
        return true;
    }
}
```

Then if it returns true it calls an install activity, and that initializes some files, and yes I know the whole array input thing is a big no no but that it besides the point (I hope) I am trying, for the time being, to keep all of the files internal, soon I will move to a server set up but as a sample/beta I want to not have to do that. The following method generateSampleStore is in the InstallActivity class:

```
private File generateSampleStore(String path) {
    File file = new File(path);
    FileOutputStream fos = null;
    try {
        fos = new FileOutputStream(file,true);
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e2) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e2.printStackTrace();
    }
    String array[] = new String[56];
    array[0] = "Store Fresh";
    array[1] = "1234 Hickory Dr. Philadelphia Pa. 12345";
    array[2] = "(123)-555-6789";
    array[3] = "24 Hours";
    array[4] = "Ketchup Aisle 1";
    array[5] = "Salt Aisle 5";
    array[6] = "Sugar Aisle 5";
    array[7] = "Peanut Butter Aisle 5";
    array[8] = "Vanilla Aisle 5";
    array[9] = "Mustard Aisle 1";
    array[10] = "Spaghetti Aisle 6";
    array[11] = "Bananas Produce-Front Right";
    array[12] = "Pam Aisle 5";
    array[13] = "Frosted Flakes Aisle 4";
    array[14] = "Bacon Deli-Back Right";
    array[15] = "Eggs Dairy-Back Left";
    array[16] = "Yogurt Dairy-Back Left";
    array[17] = "Soy Sauce Aisle 7";
    array[18] = "Coca Cola Aisle 3";
    array[19] = "Coffee Aisle 3";
    array[20] = "Tuna Aisle 1";
    array[21] = "Pickles Deli-Back Right";
    array[22] = "Hot Cocoa Aisle 5";
    array[23] = "Steak Sauce Aisle 1";
    array[24] = "All Spice Aisle 11";
    array[25] = "Elbow Macaroni Aisle 6";
    array[26] = "Lemon Juice Produce-Front Right";
    array[27] = "Garlic Produce-Front Right";
    array[28] = "Garlic Salt Aisle 5";
    array[29] = "Cheese Dairy-Back Left";
    array[30] = "Italian Dressing Aisle 1";
    array[31] = "Onion Produce-Front Right";
    array[32] = "Chicken Breasts Meat-Back Center";
    array[33] = "Ranch Dressing Aisle 1";
    array[34] = "Bread Crumbs Aisle 12";
    array[35] = "Pancake Mix Aisle 5";
    array[36] = "Cake Mix Aisle 5";
    array[37] = "Apple Sauce Aisle 5";
    array[38] = "Food Coloring Aisle 5";
    array[39] = "Apples Produce-Front Right";
    array[40] = "Potato Chips Aisle 4";
    array[41] = "Salsa Aisle 7";
    array[42] = "Ice Tea Aisle 3";
    array[43] = "Corn Syrup Aisle 5";
    array[44] = "Egg Noodles Aisle 6";
    array[45] = "Butter Dairy-Back Left";
    array[46] = "Whole Wheat Bread Aisle 12";
    array[47] = "White Bread Aisle 12";
    array[48] = "Frozen Peas Aisle 13";
    array[49] = "Vanilla Ice Cream Aisle 15";
    array[50] = "Chocolate Ice Cream Aisle 15";
    array[51] = "Chrry Water Ice Aisle 15";
    array[52] = "Shredded American Cheese Dairy-Back Left";
    array[53] = "Whipped Cream Dairy-Back Left";
    array[54] = "Ground Beef Meat-Back Center";
    array[55] = "Frozen Pizza Aisle 14";


    for(int i = 0 ; i < array.length; i ++){
    try {
        fos.write('\n');
    } catch (IOException e1) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e1.printStackTrace();
    }
    try {
        fos.write(array[i].getBytes());
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    try {
        fos.flush();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    }
    try {
        fos.close();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return file;
}
```

Then the user clicks on the "list" tab and they are brought to a menu of list names, once they click a list it calls the class openList() and the following methods are the ones in which I get the errors, there is no stacktrace because it is not a compile error, it is just doing the wrong thing(logic possibly):

The part of the onCreate() call that is relevant:

```
try {
            store = new ShoppingList(name, this).getStore();
        } catch (IOException e1) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e1.printStackTrace();
        }
    try {
        items = getItems();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    if(!(store.equalsIgnoreCase("none"))){
        try {
            Aislenum = getAisleNumbers(new Store(store, this));
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        hasAislenums = true;
    }else{
        //do nothing
    }

    if(items[0] != null){
        if(hasAislenums){
        both = connectArrays(items, Aislenum);
        setListAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.singleitem , both));
        }else{
        setListAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.singleitem , items));
        }
    }
    else{
        String New[] = new String[2];
        New[0] = "This list is empty, add your first item";
        New[1] = "by clicking the add button above";
        setListAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.singleitem , New));  
    }
    }

private String[] connectArrays(String[] item, String[] aislenum) {
    String toReturn[] = new String[item.length];

    for(int i = 0; i < item.length; i ++){
        toReturn[i] = item[i] + " " + aislenum[i];
    }
    return toReturn;
}
```

getAisleNumbers method:

```
    private String[] getAisleNumbers(Store store) {
String num[] = new String[items.length];
for(int i = 0; i < items.length; i ++){
    num[i] = store.getAisle(items[i]);
}

    return num;
}
```

connectArrays method:

```
    private String[] connectArrays(String[] item, String[] aislenum) {
    String toReturn[] = new String[item.length];

    for(int i = 0; i < item.length; i ++){
        toReturn[i] = item[i] + " " + aislenum[i];
    }
    return toReturn;
}
```

Entire Store Class:

```
package dev.shaw.MyShoppingPlanner;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.StringTokenizer;

import android.content.Context;

/*
* All store files must be written in the following format!
* 
* Header:
* 
* line 0: Store name
* line 1: Store address Format for address: ((#) Street name (rd.ln.,ave., etc.) city state zipcode
* line 2: phone number
* line 3: hours
* 
* Item Formats:
* 
* ItemName AisleNumber
* Cherios 9
* 
*/
public class Store {
Dir dir = new Dir();
private static String storename;
private static File storefile;
private static HashMap<String, String> aislenums = new HashMap<String,String>();
public Store(String store, Context context) throws IOException {
    File file = new File(context.getFilesDir() + File.separator + "Stores" +File.separator + store + ".txt");
    storename = store;
    if(file.exists()){
        //do nothing
    }else{
        try {
            file.createNewFile();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    storefile = file;
    aislenums = intAilseNums();


}
private HashMap<String, String> intAilseNums() throws IOException {
    System.out.println("Store File: "+storefile.getAbsolutePath());
    HashMap<String, String> hm = new HashMap<String,String>();
    FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(storefile);
    InputStreamReader reader = new InputStreamReader(fis);
    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(reader);
    String line = "";
    br.readLine();
    br.readLine();
    br.readLine();
    br.readLine();
    while(true){
    line = br.readLine();
    if(line == null){
        System.out.println("Line is now null");
        break;
    }
    StringTokenizer st = new StringTokenizer(line);
    String item = "";
    for(int i = 0; i < st.countTokens()- 2; i ++){
     item = item + " " + st.nextToken();
    }
    String num = st.nextToken() + " " + st.nextToken();
    hm.put(item, num);
    }

    /*br.reset();
    System.out.println(br.readLine());*/
    br.close();
    return hm;
}
public String getAisle(String item){
    return aislenums.get(item);
}
public  String getName() throws IOException{
    FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(storefile);
    InputStreamReader is = new InputStreamReader(fis); 
    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(is);
    return br.readLine();
}
public  String getAddress() throws IOException{
    String address = "";
    FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(storefile);
    InputStreamReader is = new InputStreamReader(fis); 
    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(is);
    br.readLine();
    address = br.readLine();
    br.close();
    return address;
}
public  String getStreetName() throws IOException{
    String name = "";
    FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(storefile);
    InputStreamReader is = new InputStreamReader(fis); 
    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(is);
    br.readLine();
    String line = br.readLine();
    StringTokenizer st = new StringTokenizer(line);
    st.nextToken();
    name = st.nextToken() + " " + st.nextToken();
    br.close();
    return name;
}
public  String getCity() throws IOException{
    String city = "";
    FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(storefile);
    InputStreamReader is = new InputStreamReader(fis); 
    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(is);
    br.readLine();
    String line = br.readLine();
    StringTokenizer st = new StringTokenizer(line);
    st.nextToken();
    st.nextToken();
    st.nextToken();
    city = st.nextToken();

    br.close();
    return city;
}
public  String getState() throws IOException{
    String state = "";
    FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(storefile);
    InputStreamReader is = new InputStreamReader(fis); 
    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(is);
    br.readLine();
    String line = br.readLine();
    StringTokenizer st = new StringTokenizer(line);
    st.nextToken();
    st.nextToken();
    st.nextToken();
    st.nextToken();
    state  = st.nextToken();
    br.close();
    return state;
}
public  String getZipCodeAsString() throws IOException{
    String zipcode = "";
    FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(storefile);
    InputStreamReader is = new InputStreamReader(fis); 
    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(is);
    br.readLine();
    String line = br.readLine();
    StringTokenizer st = new StringTokenizer(line);
    st.nextToken();
    st.nextToken();
    st.nextToken();
    st.nextToken();
    st.nextToken();
    zipcode  = st.nextToken();
    br.close();
    return zipcode;
}
public  int getZipCodeAsInteger() throws IOException{
    int zipcode = 0;
    FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(storefile);
    InputStreamReader is = new InputStreamReader(fis); 
    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(is);
    br.readLine();
    String line = br.readLine();
    StringTokenizer st = new StringTokenizer(line);
    st.nextToken();
    st.nextToken();
    st.nextToken();
    st.nextToken();
    st.nextToken();
    zipcode  = Integer.parseInt(st.nextToken());
    br.close();
    return zipcode;
}
public  String getPhoneNumber() throws IOException{
    String num = "";
    FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(storefile);
    InputStreamReader is = new InputStreamReader(fis); 
    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(is);
    br.readLine();
    br.readLine();
    num = br.readLine();
    br.close();
    return num;
}
public static  File getFile(){
    return storefile;
}
public  String getHours() throws IOException{
    FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(storefile);
    InputStreamReader is = new InputStreamReader(fis); 
    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(is);
    br.readLine();
    br.readLine();
    br.readLine();
    String hours = br.readLine();
    br.close();
    return hours;


}
```

}

Comment: have you every heard of debugging?  At least tell us what is (or is not) happening?

Comment: http://gyazo.com/b9e2f84e619c9fcc94a056fd7d40d65f this is the output, I have connected the two arrays into an array of one string but for some reason the "Aislenums" array is always null and for some reason the data file is always empty

Comment: so either some exception is being thrown that you are not telling us about, or you logic is incorrect.  Try putting some debugging information in and find out where it is going wrong.  This is bread and butter developer stuff.

Comment: I'm pretty sure it is my logic because the stack trace has no exceptions being thrown, which honestly I would prefer. And yes I know this is bread and butter dev stuff, but I fairly new to android, only about a month, and I have been fighting this one bug for about a week so I thought someone might be able to catch a logic error that I wasn't finding.